# Can a value of a case class contain itself in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, recursion, case

Given a tree of following shape:

```
enum Tree
  case Node(left: Tree, right:Tree)
  case Leaf
```

is it possible to create a value `n:Node`, such that `n.left == n || n.right == n`?
`val n:Node = Node(n,n)` does not work, but is there a compile-time guarantee that no such value can exist? Is there such a guarantee (ie that `a.a==a` may never hold for any `a:A` where `A` is a case class) for case classes in general?

A bit of additional context:
I came upon this issue because I need to know whether a collection of `Tree`s shapes up to a single, well-formed tree, and at one point wanted to check, whether said collection has any `Node`s that refer to themselves.

Comment: with var it is possible : https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m7F5LBqsSNKMpD6X4G4C0Q

Comment: You can use it using `lazy val`, you can also do it using an auxiliary constructor, and you may do it with `copy` and an intermediate `val` or a `var`. - So yeah, is possible, just rarely useful IMHO.

Comment: @volia17 Thank you, but I do not think that a equals a.left or a.right after line 16 in that particular snippet.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you. After some thinking, since IIRC case classes are compared by value, it should be definitely be possible to construct a case class using a variable (constant or not) in the constructor parameter list that has the same value, haven't thought about the lazy way though. Also can't think of any possible uses, but definitely seems possible to encounter such a value.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, On second tought, I still can't see it. To clarify, I am looking for a value `a` of any case class `A`, where `A` has a a member of type `A` or maybe type `B<:A`, and `a.member == a` evaluates to `true`

Comment: So in theory you could do something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kZU2lfjOQdaBJpkQinGECw/1 but this produces an infinite loop,, I think there are ways to avoid that, but again, is kind of weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With class (and case class is not exception) you are eagerly evaluating every expression passed as an argument to the constructor. `lazy` or `def` will not help, because at the end of the day you have to obtain the reference, and you cannot obtain it before the constructor is run. Inside the constructor is actually the first time you obtain the reference to the (not yet fully constructed) object.

You'd have to use `var` or runtime reflection to set this value:

```
final case class Data(var data: Data)

val data = locally {
  val recurData = Data(null.asInstanceOf[Data])
  recurData.data = recurData
  recurData
}

data.data == data
```

([version with var](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/tcyqGBGCT36xhI2XPqKL5A))

```
final case class Data(data: Data)

val data = locally {
  val recurData = Data(null.asInstanceOf[Data])
  val field = recurData.getClass.getDeclaredField("data")
  field.setAccessible(true)
  field.set(recurData, recurData)
  recurData
}

data.data == data
```

([version with reflection](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/P1kmMVHBRaaky1eQ7t0rdA))

If this was not a case class you could do some weird stuff in constructor's body - if you set the `val` yourself you could use some logic to decide where the reference comes from and `this` as reference [would be accessible](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/tcyqGBGCT36xhI2XPqKL5A/6).

```
class WeirdClass private (refE: Either[Unit, WeirdClass]) {
  def this() = this(Left(()))
  def this(ref: WeirdClass) = this(Right(ref))

  val ref: WeirdClass = refE.getOrElse(this)
}

val w = new WeirdClass()
w.ref == w
```

Normal case class, even with auxiliary constructors, would not let you do such thing with a `val` defined in a constructor argument list - vals from constructor argument list are initiated with the value you passed it and there is no way to customize it (even defaults are executed before the constructor is called) and auxilary constructors do not let you use `this` as anything other than something to call (`this(this)` results in compilation error).

So as long as you are using normal case class, let Scala generate the `val`s definition and make sure that nobody uses vars nor reflection, it should never happen.